# How to map old paths to Drupal paths

Tags: drupal, url, mapping

I'm converting a Wordpress blog to Drupal and need to map the WP paths to the new Drupal ones.
What's the best practice for doing this? There are only around a hundred pages to map. I've been experimenting with the URL Alter module, which provides an alternative to messing with custom_url_rewrite functions settings.php but keep getting 404. Waiting to hear back from the module maintainer if this is what the module is intended for. In the meantime I am wondering how others do this? Should I be using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this page](http://drupal.org/project/wp2drupal) could help you to merge your wordpress blog into drupals with WP2Drupal.

> You can use Path_Redirect to catch the old URLs but still use PathAuto to give them new URLs; GlobalRedirect will make it even more transparent

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up lifting some ideas from Global Redirect and just using drupal_goto in a hook_init.